# String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() vs is null

Tags: c#, .net

I just want to be sure that doing this makes sense in C# 11.0 (.NET 7):

```
if (filePath is null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
    return false;
```

My thought is that IsNull... uses '==' operator, that can be overloaded, while 'is' can not.

Comment: Seems redundant to me - can you explain the scenario further where this would not be the case?

Comment: You don't need `if (filePath is null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))`.  If you are checking for null, check `filePath is null`.  If you are checking if the string is empty or null, you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)`.  If you consider a string that contains only whitespace effectively empty, use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)`.  In general, you should consider Microsoft-sourced code as good or better than anything you write; there's no need to second-guess them.  BTW, the pattern matching `filePath is null`, is a recent addition to the language, it was always `==null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly your code is redundant: if `filePath` is `string` then

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)) {
  ...
}
```

is enough. "Almost" is for exotic case when `filePath` is of type like this:

```
public class MyPath {
  ...

  public static implicit operator string(MyPath value) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this case your current code with double check makes sense:

```
MyPath filePath = ...

if (filePath is null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)) {
  ...
}
```

we check if `filePath` is `null` or when it's not `null` its `string` representation is `null` or consists of white spaces only.